# Is it possible to change the height of the placeholder rows in UITableView without creating dummy row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

The row height beyond the last row in TableView (*the empty placeholder rows that are just there for visual detail if the number of items is less than the number of rows a TableView can display at once*) is always the same as the last row height.

**Is it possible to change this without resorting to adding a dummy last row?**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is no row beyond the last row in a TableView (unless I am misunderstanding the word *last*).

Comment: @PengOne I am referring to the placeholder rows that are there when the number of item is less than the number of rows a TableView can accommodate.

Comment: resize the tableView frame height to hide the placeholder rows ?

Comment: Err, without resorting to that too, lol. I don't want to hide it. Essentially, I have variable row heights for certain cells, but I want  the placeholder rows to have a fixed default height instead of whatever the last row height is. I am able to do this by adding a dummy, empty, unselectable row with the desired height at the end, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private `UITableView` instance method `_spacingForExtraSeparators` returns the height of the placeholder rows.  If you're not writing an app for the App Store, just override that.  It returns a CGFloat.

Here's an different approach that is App Store-compliant (as far as I know), and might be easier than creating a dummy row.

`UITableView` sends itself the `layoutSubviews` message a lot.  It does this whenever it adds, removes, or rearranges cells, and whenever it scrolls (and probably other times too).  So let's override `layoutSubviews` to draw a view that starts at the bottom edge of your table view's last section.  The view will be filled with a repeating pattern that looks like placeholder cells,  with a height you define.

Create a subclass of `UITableView`.  Give your subclass a `UIView *_bottomView` instance variable. We need to override `layoutSubviews`, so we'll initialize `_bottomView` lazily in that method.

```
@implementation MyTableView
{
    UIView *_bottomView;
}
```

Override `layoutSubviews`.  The first thing you do in your `layoutSubviews` is call `[super layoutSubviews]` so you'll continue to act like a proper `UITableView`.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
```

The next thing you do is lazily initialize `_bottomView`.

```
    if (!_bottomView) {
```

You need a pattern to fill `_bottomView`, and it needs to look like placeholder cells.  Make  an image context that's 1 pixel wide, and as tall as you want a placeholder cell to be.  Fill the context with white, and paint a separator line (pixel, really) at the bottom.  Get the image from the context.

```
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1, placeholderHeight), YES, 0);
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
        UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, placeholderHeight));
        [self.separatorColor setFill];
        UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, placeholderHeight - 1, 1, 1));
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Next, create `_bottomView`, set its background "color" to that image as a repeating pattern, and add it to yourself as a subview.

```
        _bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _bottomView.opaque = YES;
        _bottomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
        [self addSubview:_bottomView];
    } // end of if-block
```

Finally, find the rect of your last section.  Use that rect to compute a frame for `_bottomView` that starts at the bottom of the last section, is plenty tall (twice your own height is more than enough), and is as wide as the last section's rect.

```
    int lastSectionIndex = [self.dataSource numberOfSectionsInTableView:self] - 1;
    if (lastSectionIndex < 0)
        lastSectionIndex = 0;
    CGRect lastSectionRect = [self rectForSection:lastSectionIndex];
    CGRect bottomViewFrame = CGRectMake(lastSectionRect.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxY(lastSectionRect), lastSectionRect.size.width, self.bounds.size.height * 2);
    _bottomView.frame = bottomViewFrame;
```

Finally, make sure `_bottomView` is your frontmost subview so it will overdraw `UITableView`'s placeholder cells.

```
    [self bringSubviewToFront:_bottomView];
} // end of layoutSubviews
```

The end.

```
@end
```

Comment: I have changed my answer.  This should be easier than using a dummy row.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer :) Not sure if this is easier than using a dummy row, though. It only takes 7 lines of code for me.

Comment: I guess it depends on the complexity of your model, whether you allow editing, whether you use a row menu, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a public API to do so. It is reasonable to use the last row height as the placeholder rows height.

If you insist on changing the height of placeholder rows, as I know, add an empty dummy cell at the end of your cells is the only way to do so.

Just as you've done.